# Need help animating a collection instance with parented empty

Tags: animation, collections

I am unable to animate Child Collection Instance with parent empty.
Here’s a short clip of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tImQT.jpg

Could anyone please help me to understand what’s the issue and how to fix it?

Also here's the blend file, in case anyone needs to inspect it :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're messing up with the parentage. Actually object B and C are parented to object A. But object C is an instance of object B, so C is **twice** subject to the influence of A.

So you need to either deparent B, make it invisible and only use C objects, or don't use C and duplicate B.

[image]

Comment: Are you questioning the OP's parentage,?

Comment: the objects parentage  ;)  how would you say it? (english is not my native language)

Comment: All good,  Was a poor attempt on my part at black humour.

Comment: yes, I suspected but I was not sure  ;)

Comment: Thank you moonboots! I was treating the instance as copy! thanks for the clear explanation.
There's nothing wrong with your English, I often find non-native speakers communicate more clearly than the native speakers! not sure why!